# How to fix a discord.py not working kick command

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So I have a problem with this kick command, I do not get any errors, nothing happens, here's the code:

```
@client.command()
async def kick(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason=None):

    await member.kick(reason=reason)

    await ctx.send(f'User {member} has kicked.')
```

Also **yes I have restarted the bot**, I also have other commands like this one that just don't work. Here's the more important part of the whole code for the bot.

```
import os
import requests
import json
import random
from discord.ext import commands
from keep_alive import keep_alive
from replit import db



client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '$')

#$kick
@client.command()
async def kick(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason=None):

    await member.kick(reason=reason)

    await ctx.send(f'User {member} has kicked.')
TOKEN
client.run(os.getenv("TOKEN"))
```

Comment: I think you have to use [`Bot.process_commands(ctx)`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.process_commands) because otherwise, the command functions aren't called.

Comment: Use it in your `on_message()` function, so it's ensured that the commands are being run.